# Insert data from query into a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to execute a query that will give me just 1 row. 
Then I want to insert that data into a form, so I can then edit it and do other actions submitting the data, but that's not the point.

```
<form method="post">

        <label for="Azienda">Azienda</label>
            <input type="text" id="Azienda" name="Azienda" value="<?php echo escape($row["Azienda"]); ?>">
```

Hypothetically, I should see the data of the first field, taken from the query, inserted in the first label of the form, but it's blank.

This is the code from where I get the results.

```
$name = $_GET['Azienda'];

        $sql = "SELECT [...]
                FROM [...]
                WHERE [...] = :name
                ORDER BY [...]";

            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Not enough details: how do you go from your SQL query to the `$row` array? How is function `escape` defined ?

Comment: The answer to all questions concerning "it's blank" is dump, dump, dump. Dump the `$row`, dump the result of `escape()` on that row, dump any related things in the code. See what your variables contain. Whenever some unexpected behaviour occurs, you have an error in your logic. Either a variable doesn't contain what you think or your conditions are off. Whatever it is, you need to do the debugging because we can't run your code.

Comment: I have dumped $result and it shows me that it got all the data. So I'm wondering if there's an error in the code of the form, as I retrieved all the data.

Comment: Everything is there in the page, the title, the form. The data is retrieved but nothing is inserted into the labels of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't defining $row, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very small problem. You should simply add the following code to your `.php` file given below:

```html
<form method="post">
    <label for="Azienda">Azienda</label>
    <input type="text" id="Azienda" name="Azienda" value="
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";     //database name
    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name";
    $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["azienda"];//write your column name here which you want to fetch from database
    }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

?>">
```

I hope your problem will be solved